# Display certain folder content

Tags: php, directory

Is it possible to display only certain content from a folder in a webpage?
I have managed to use a 'php' script with `readdir` to display all of the folder content as a list:

```
<?php
    $dir = opendir('y1');
    echo '<ul>';
    while ($read = readdir($dir))
    {
        if ($read!='.' && $read!='..')
        {
            echo '<li><a href="y1/'.$read.'"><span class="clicks">'.$read.'</span></a></li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    closedir($dir); 
?>
```

Is it possible to adapt this code to only show for example all the files beginning with the letter 'n'?

Comment: add `if($read[0] == 'n') {` before echoing

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use substr to check the 1st letter.

```
<?php
$dir = opendir('y1');
echo '<ul>';
while ($read = readdir($dir))
{
    if (substr($read,0,1)=='n') //<--here
    {
        echo '<li><a href="y1/'.$read.'"><span class="clicks">'.$read.'</span></a></li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
closedir($dir); 
?>
```

Your original checks for `'.'` and `'..'` are no longer needed, as they dont start with `n` either

Answer (score 0):

try this one to get those `files` which names are starting from `n`

with condition `if ($read[0]=='n')` like this

```
<?php
    $dir = opendir('y1');
    echo '<ul>';
    while ($read = readdir($dir))
    {
        if ($read[0]=='n')
        {
            echo '<li><a href="y1/'.$read.'"><span class="clicks">'.$read.'</span></a></li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    closedir($dir); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_match()`](http://nz1.php.net/preg_match) which uses a [regular expression](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) which will return either true or false if the [pattern](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) is found in the string or not.

```
<?php
$dir = opendir('y1');
echo '<ul>';
while ($read = readdir($dir))
{
    if (preg_match("/^[n]/i", $read))
    {
        echo '<li><a href="y1/'.$read.'"><span class="clicks">'.$read.'</span></a></li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
closedir($dir); 
?>
```

Using this means you can adapt the code to only display files that contain any pattern.

For instance a file that end in `.png` or `.jpg`.